# How to access FormController created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of items. Each item will be associated to a form dynamically by using `ng-repeat` and `ng-form`.

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people" ng-form="person.$form">
    ...
</div>
```

Then I have the possibility of *creating* new items. But when I do that, I want their new form to get **dirty**.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addPerson()">ADD NEW ONE...</button>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.addPerson = function() {
  var p = {
    name: 'Charles',
    color: 'green'
  };
  $scope.people.push(p);

  p.$form.$setDirty(); // <----- THIS WON'T WORK
};
```

As written in the above comment, this won't work. It tries to execute that instruction *before* the *FormController* has been created.

I was not able to find any solution for this so far, nor a fully related answered question here.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nhTE5ZgXDrnN8WMf2IDT) is a Plunker for this example, enriched with some buttons and labels to play with dirty and pristine states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to initialize the form:

```
app.directive("initForm", function() {
  return {
    link: postLink,
    require: 'form'
  }
  function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,form) {
    form.$setDirty();
  }
})
```

And use that in the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people" init-form ng-form="person.$form">
    ...
</div>
```

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mmWh96BaJi1ktwMuRV3C?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.people = [
    {name: 'Alice',
     color: 'pink'
    },
    {name: 'Bob',
     color: 'blue'
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.addPerson = function() {
    var p = {
      name: 'Charles',
      color: 'green'
    };
    $scope.people.push(p);
    
    //p.$form.$setDirty();
  };
  
})

.directive("initForm", function() {
  return {
    link: postLink,
    require: 'form'
  }
  function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,form) {
    form.$setDirty();
  }
})
```

```css
.ng-pristine {
  background-color: #E0F8F7;
}

.ng-dirty {
  background-color: #F5A9BC;
}

.bigform.ng-pristine {
  background-color: #5882FA;
}

.bigform.ng-dirty {
  background-color: #FF0040;
}

.bigform {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-form="mainForm" class="bigform">
      <div ng-repeat="person in people" 
           init-form
           ng-form="person.$form">
          <p>{{personIndex}}</p>
          <input type="text" ng-model="person.name" />
          <input type="text" ng-model="person.color" />
          <button type="button" ng-click="person.$form.$setPristine()">RE-PRISTINATE</button>
          <label>form is <span ng-show="person.$form.$dirty">dirty</span><span ng-show="person.$form.$pristine">pristine</span></label>
        <br />
      </div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button type="button" ng-click="mainForm.$setPristine()">RELOAD</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" ng-click="addPerson()">ADD NEW ONE...</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, although I want the initial forms to keep pristine. I guess the best way is to set a _$new_ field on new "person" items and an attribute to read in the directive which sets the form to `$dirty` or not basing on the value of `person.$new`.

Comment: Eventually I also found another solution which is putting the `$setDirty()` instruction in a `$timeout()` to wait for the _FormController_ to fully initialize.
I wonder if this was suitable from a "best practices" perspective and, in case, which one is better.

Comment: Using [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) a symptom of a more fundamental problem. While it may work, it is a fragile solution. It is better to find a deterministic robust approach to a problem. In this case code was executing before the associated form controller was instantiated by the AngularJS framework. It is better to use a mechanism that is guaranteed to occur at the proper time. Directives are compiled by the framework in a specific sequence that is deterministic.